# Conditional format WITHIN cell using R to Excel

Tags: r, excel, xlconnect, openxlsx

*Input*: "A dog is here."

*Rule*: Bold "dog"

*Output*: "A **dog** is here."

The output would be within, e.g., cell A1 of Excel.

Most conditional formatting using R to Excel (e.g., openxlsx) formats the entire cell, but I'm looking to format partial strings within a cell.

Is there a package or function for this in R? (It looks like there are VBA options, but I need to do this within R).

Answer (score 1):

Conditional Formatting is all or nothing.

The best thing to do would be to use VBA to edit all text where this applies and have the script run every time you open/close the workbook

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for an R solution without VBA.